# Norm of a Vector in a Number Field (or Order in a Number Field)

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory

I am looking for a measurement, which gives a length of a vector in a number Field? Is there any way or definition for that. 
For the Maximal order, What if, I tried to define a map from Maximal order to a Lattice. Is there any way to define a isomorphism from a order of a number field to a lattice. Please give me a example or a reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A standard way to measure the size (= complexity) of vectors with coordinates in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ is through the theory of Weil height functions. You can find the definition and properties of the Weil height
$$ H : \mathbb P^n(\overline{\mathbb Q}) \longrightarrow [1,\infty) $$
in many places, such as [1] and [2]. Since you are asking about vectors, rather than points in projective space, you probably want to use the embedding
$$ \overline{\mathbb Q}{}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb P^n(\overline{\mathbb Q}),\qquad
(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \longmapsto [1,a_1,\ldots,a_n] $$
and then take the height.

Among the many nice properties of $H$ is the fact that for any given number field $K$, the number of points in $\mathbb P^n(K)$ with height $H(P)\le C$ is finite. There's even an estimate for the number of such points as $C\to\infty$ due to Schanuel.

1. *Fundamentals of Diophantine Geometry*, S. Lang, Springer, 1983.
2. *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, J.H. Silverman, Springer, 2009.

**Addendum to Answer OP's Comment:** Let $A$ be a matrix with entries in a number field $K$, and let
$\boldsymbol{a}_1,\ldots,\boldsymbol{a}_n$ be its column vectors. We define the absolute value of a vector to be the max of the absolute values of its coordinates. Then the
following should be more-or-less correct, although one has to be a bit
careful about the normalizations of the absolute values.
$$
\begin{aligned}
  H(\det A) &= \prod_{v\in M_K} \max\bigl\{ \|\det A\|_v, 1 \bigr\}\qquad\text{(definition of $H$)} \\
  &\le \prod_{v\in M_K} \max\bigl\{ \|\boldsymbol{a}_1\|_v\cdot\|\boldsymbol{a}_2\|_v\cdots\|\boldsymbol{a}_n\|_v, 1 \bigr\}
    \qquad\text{(Hadamard)} \\
  &\le \prod_{v\in M_K} \prod_{i=1}^n \max\bigl\{ \|\boldsymbol{a}_i\|_v, 1 \bigr\}  \\
  &= \prod_{i=1}^n H( \boldsymbol{a}_i)\qquad\text{(definition of $H$)}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Joseph. Actually, I wanted to find a bound for a determinant of a matrix over a number field. Hoping to try your idea with the Hadamard bound. If you have any nice idea, I am happy to know. Thanks again.

Comment: @Joy I hope, here, $M_k$ is the set of standard absolute values of K (a complete set of inequivalent absolute values on) and   all the notations comes from your book TAEC. I am sorry, but ${||a||}_v$ is not that clear, as I am new to this topic. I will try to understand this. Thank you very much for your kind consideration in this regards.

Comment: Yes, it's the set of standard absolute values, but normalized so that (1) the product formula holds without having to raise to powers and (2) the value is independent of which number field you use. So if $|a|_v$ denotes the extension of a standard absolute value on $\mathbb Q$ to a number field $K$, then $\|a\|_v = |a|_v^{[K_v:\mathbb Q_v]/[K:\mathbb Q]}$. Here $K_v$ is the completion of $K$ at $v$, so $[K_v:\mathbb Q_v]$ is the local degree. Dividing the exponent by $[K:\mathbb Q]$ has the effect of making the value independent of the choice of the number field containing $a$.